# customize tastypie patch_list

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I use the patch_list metodo in order to save and delete my resources. 
At the moment I need a way to call an external procedure on the entire list before the response is sent to the client.

Is there a better way than copy and paste the code of patch_list in my sources and modify it?
Are there some hooks at list level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the hook - alter_list_data_to_serialize.
Which is called just before creating the response.

```
def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
    #call external procedure here
    return data
```

data is the list to be serialized.